# How can scrapy be used to extract the link graph of a website?

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

Given a starting URL `start` (and some rules on admissible domains etc) I would like to produce a directed graph (V, E) where the nodes in `V` are the pages reachable from `start`, and there is an arc `(u,v)` in `E` whenever there is a hyperlink on page `u` pointing to page `v`.

Is there a simple way to obtain such a graph with `scrapy`? I would also be happy using another open source tool if it can achieve the goal more easily/nicely.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know any tools or contrib which is producing precisely what you want. You'll have to build a scrapy spider to to that. I can explain here the necessary steps:

- Create a scrapy project and generate a default spider

  ```
  $ scrapy startproject sitegraph
  $ cd sitegraph
  $ scrapy genspider graphspider mydomain.com
  ```
- This will create a directory with a items.py file. Add the following lines in this file

  ```
  from scrapy.item import Item, Field

  class SitegraphItem(Item):
       url=Field()
       linkedurls=Field()
  ```
- in the spiders directory you will find graphspider.py replace it by (of course mydomain.com need to be replaced):

  ```
  from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
  from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
  from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
  from scrapy.utils.url import urljoin_rfc
  from sitegraph.items import SitegraphItem

  class GraphspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
      name = 'graphspider'
      allowed_domains = ['mydomain.com']
      start_urls = ['http://mydomain/index.html']

      rules = (
          Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
      )

      def parse_item(self, response):
          hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
          i = SitegraphItem()
          i['url'] = response.url
          i['http_status'] = response.status
          llinks=[]
          for anchor in hxs.select('//a[@href]'):
              href=anchor.select('@href').extract()[0]
              if not href.lower().startswith("javascript"):
          llinks.append(urljoin_rfc(response.url,href))
          i['linkedurls'] = llinks
          return i
  ```
- then edit the settings.py file and add (change the file name accordingly):

  ```
  FEED_FORMAT="jsonlines"
  FEED_URI="file:///tmp/sitegraph.json"
  ```
- now you can run:

  ```
  $ scrapy crawl graphspider
  ```
- this will generate a json file the you can use to build a graph.

You can use a package like networkx to analyse it ot pygraphviz to draw it (not recommanded for large sites)

```
import json
import pygraphviz as pg

def loadgraph(fname):
        G=pg.AGraph(directed=True)
        for line in open(fname):
            j=json.loads(line)
            url=j["url"]
            G.add_node(url)
            for linked_url in j["linkedurls"]:
                G.add_edge(url,linked_url)
        return G

if __name__=='__main__':
        G=loadgraph("/tmp/sitegraph.json")
        G.layout(prog='dot')
        G.draw("sitegraph.png")
```

Comment: I am new to scrapy, I have followed your above posted answer for sitegraph, I have some doubts :-
**1) I have list of url's and want to come up with the site graph for all the url's in the list, how can we do that ?
2) I want to utilize the crawled content of the respective page
3) I would like to store the site graph with it's content in hdfs, how can we achieve that ?**
I am completely new to these topics, please help me out.